# Display certain items from an array on user key press c#

Tags: c#, arrays

So my task is to create some code that will ask the user to press a key between 1 and 6. These keys will then correspond to the 6 names of people in an array called "names". So for example if the "1" key is pressed, the console will output "Jack" as that is the first item in the array. If they don't press one of these keys the console will output "Incorrect Input". I've spent around 3 hours trying to figure out how to do this, and apparently I would have to covert the names into integers, but I have no clue how. This is what I currently have, and I know that it is not much... but if anyone can help, I'd appreciate very much. Thanks.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a key 1-6");

            ConsoleKeyInfo readText;

            string[] names = { "Jack", "Eduardo", "Joe", "Will", "Felix", "Lukas" };

            ConsoleKeyInfo name = Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following to get only one character from the console as an input of the user.

```
var character = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
```

Then you could check if this character matches your criteria and act correspondingly.

```
if (character >= '1' && character <= '6')
{
    var value = (int) char.GetNumericValue(character);
    var index = value - 1;
    Console.WriteLine(names[index]); 
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Input");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var character = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
int key = (int)character;
if(key < 1 || key > 6)
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect Input");
else
    Console.WriteLine(names[(int)key]);
```